# Problem about using groupby on a list column with categorical values, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

I have a json data about science questions; each question can have a parameter as follows:

```
[{'Question': 'What is the scientific method  and why is it important?',
 'parameters': 'a 7-11 year-old person',
 'Response': {'It's a method for finding answers to questions',
  'analysis': {'text_num_chars': 63,
   'text_num_words': 8,
   'text_num_sents': 1}}},
{'Question': 'What is the difference between a theory and a hypothesis?',
 'parameters': '8th & 9th graders',
 'Response': {'theory is an explanation of a phenomenon that is based on observations, experiments, and data.A hypothesis, on the other hand, is a testable statement about the natural world that can be used to build more complex hypotheses or theories.',
  'analysis': {'text_num_chars': 283,
   'text_num_words': 34,
   'text_num_sents': 2}}},
...
]
```

I tried to build a data frame from json first, then try to groupby based on parameters to find `mean()` value of `text_num_chars and text_num_words`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions': lst_questions, 
                   'Parameters': lst_parameters,
                   'Metrics': lst_metrics})
```

Here is `print (df['Metrics'].head(2).tolist())`

```
[{'text_num_chars': 673, 'text_num_words': 100, 'text_num_sents': 5}, {'text_num_chars': 635, 'text_num_words': 101, 'text_num_sents': 7}]
```

In the end, I want to plot these results as:

values of parameters (X axis), what is the `mean()` value of the text_num_chars for each parameter (Y axis).

Comment: you can use `groupby.plot`, it is plotting one figure per group. But my guess is that it isn't what you want. Can you provide a reproducible example (as code)? and a mockup of the expected graph?

Comment: Edit the title of your question to reflect the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for `level/ score` columns and aggregate `mean`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions': ['What is gravity?', 'What is evaporation?', 'What are isotopes?',
                                 'what is an earthquake?'], 
                   'Parameters': ['Elementary school', 'Highschool school', '', 'Elementary school'],
                   'Metrics': [{'level': 4, 'score': 5}, {'level': 6, 'score': 7}, 
                               {'level': 10, 'score': 6}, {'level': 2, 'score': 3}]})
```

---

```
df = pd.json_normalize(df['Metrics']).groupby(df['Parameters']).mean()
print (df)
                   level  score
Parameters                     
                      10      6
Elementary school      3      4
Highschool school      6      7
```

Then ploting:

```
df.plot()
```

EDIT: Test yout data (not valid, so added to keys):

```
data = [{'Question': 'What is the scientific method  and why is it important?',
 'parameters': 'a 7-11 year-old person',
 'Response': {'Its a method for finding answers to questions':'aaa','analysis': {'text_num_chars': 63,'text_num_words': 8,'text_num_sents': 1}}},
{'Question': 'What is the difference between a theory and a hypothesis?',
 'parameters': '8th & 9th graders',
 'Response': {'theory is an explanation of a phenomenon that is based on observations, experiments, and data.A hypothesis, on the other hand, is a testable statement about the natural world that can be used to build more complex hypotheses or theories.':'test',
  'analysis': {'text_num_chars': 283,
   'text_num_words': 34,
   'text_num_sents': 2}}}]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
                                            Question              parameters  \
0  What is the scientific method  and why is it i...  a 7-11 year-old person   
1  What is the difference between a theory and a ...       8th & 9th graders   

                                            Response  
0  {'Its a method for finding answers to question...  
1  {'theory is an explanation of a phenomenon tha...  

df = pd.json_normalize(df['Response']).groupby(df['parameters']).mean()
print (df)
                        analysis.text_num_chars  analysis.text_num_words  \
parameters                                                                 
8th & 9th graders                           283                       34   
a 7-11 year-old person                       63                        8   

                        analysis.text_num_sents  
parameters                                       
8th & 9th graders                             2  
a 7-11 year-old person                        1
```

Comment: I get this error:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: What is `print (df['Metrics'].head(4).tolist())` ?

Comment: It's the list of dictionaries for metrics as follow: 
`[{'level': 4, 'score':5}, {'level': 6, 'score':7}, {'level': 10, 'score':6},{'level': 3, 'score':3}]`

Comment: @Donya - aded data to answer, your real data are different?

Comment: Yes, It's so big that's why I simplified it. I think the problem is the type of my column which is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` and with your code returns `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @Donya - Is not possible add to question `print (df['Metrics'].head(4).tolist())` with real data ?

Comment: Here also the output for `Parameters` column:
`['an under 7 year-old kid', 'a 7-11 year-old person', 'an 11-17 year-old person', 'a person older than 17']`

Comment: What is `print (df['Metrics'].head(4).tolist())` ?

Comment: Error means data are different like `[{'level': 4, 'score':5}, {'level': 6, 'score':7}, {'level': 10, 'score':6},{'level': 3, 'score':3}]` , s I ask for real data append to question. Without it hard found what is problem.

Comment: Thanks, Here is the data:

print(df.iloc[0])

`Questions     Can you tell me, for an under 7 year-old kid, ...
Parameters                              an under 7 year-old kid
Metrics       {'text_num_chars': 673, 'text_num_words': 100,...
Name: 0, dtype: object`

Comment: Unfortunatly this format cannot use for DataFrame. So ask again What is `print (df['Metrics'].head(4).tolist())` If not possible add to comment, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75694344/edit) question?

Comment: Question updated. I hope it can help me this way.

Comment: Maybe problem is something else, what is `print (df['Parameters'].head(4).tolist())` ?

Comment: @Donya - In another words, what should be difference between `df = pd.DataFrame(...` and your real data?

Comment: @Donya - I test your data from question and for me working perfect, added to answer.

Comment: I think the problem of my data was the parameters column which had both strings and lists. I used `df['parameters'] = [' '.join([str(c) for c in lst]) for lst in df['parameters']]` to convert all to string and now it's working. Thanks